# rotate images in specific angle, CSS3 or Canvas?

Tags: html, css, canvas, stylesheet

Here is the first screen shot. This was excepted from the assignment.

[image: what i want to achieve]

As the screen shot suggest, user will upload image 1. And it will look like image 2. The final output is expected as shown.

I tried to do same thing using CSS3. Here is what i have achieved after long time

[image: what i have achieved]

i am try to achieve same thing in CSS3.

Here is the HTML i tried

```
<div id="gallery">
        <a class="a row1" href="./example/9_b.jpg" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img alt="" src="./example/9_s.jpg" /></a>
        <a class="b row1" href="./example/10_b.jpg" title=""><img alt="" src="./example/10_s.jpg" /></a>
        <a class="c row1" href="./example/11_b.jpg" title=""><img alt="" src="./example/11_s.jpg" /></a>
        <a class="d row1" href="./example/12_b.jpg" title=""><img class="last" alt="" src="./example/12_s.jpg" /></a>
        <a class="e row1" href="./example/9_b.jpg" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img alt="" src="./example/9_s.jpg" /></a>
        <a class="f row1" href="./example/10_b.jpg" title=""><img alt="" src="./example/10_s.jpg" /></a>
        <a class="g row1" href="./example/11_b.jpg" title=""><img alt="" src="./example/11_s.jpg" /></a>


        <a class="a row2" href="./example/9_b.jpg" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img alt="" src="./example/9_s.jpg" /></a>
        <a class="b row2" href="./example/10_b.jpg" title=""><img alt="" src="./example/10_s.jpg" /></a>
        <a class="c row2" href="./example/11_b.jpg" title=""><img alt="" src="./example/11_s.jpg" /></a>
        <a class="d row2" href="./example/12_b.jpg" title=""><img class="last" alt="" src="./example/12_s.jpg" /></a>
        <a class="e row2" href="./example/9_b.jpg" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img alt="" src="./example/9_s.jpg" /></a>
        <a class="f row2" href="./example/10_b.jpg" title=""><img alt="" src="./example/10_s.jpg" /></a>
        <a class="g row2" href="./example/11_b.jpg" title=""><img alt="" src="./example/11_s.jpg" /></a>

        <a class="a row3" href="./example/9_b.jpg" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img alt="" src="./example/9_s.jpg" /></a>
        <a class="b row3" href="./example/10_b.jpg" title=""><img alt="" src="./example/10_s.jpg" /></a>
        <a class="c row3" href="./example/11_b.jpg" title=""><img alt="" src="./example/11_s.jpg" /></a>
        <a class="d row3" href="./example/12_b.jpg" title=""><img class="last" alt="" src="./example/12_s.jpg" /></a>
        <a class="e row3" href="./example/9_b.jpg" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img alt="" src="./example/9_s.jpg" /></a>
        <a class="f row3" href="./example/10_b.jpg" title=""><img alt="" src="./example/10_s.jpg" /></a>
        <a class="g row3" href="./example/11_b.jpg" title=""><img alt="" src="./example/11_s.jpg" /></a>

        <div class="caption">
            this is test caption
        </div>
        <div class="close">
            X
        </div>

        <div class="next">></div>
        <div class="prev"><</div>
    </div>
```

And here is the css for it

```
#gallery {
    width: 600px;
    height: 450px;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: #999;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
}

.galleryed {
    z-index: 100;
}

.galleryed a {
    display: none;
}

.caption {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #333;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    padding: 2%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 96%;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.caption:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.close {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #333;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    padding: 2%;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.next:hover,.prev:hover,.close:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.next {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #333;
    top: 200px;
    right: 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    padding: 2%;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.prev {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #333;
    top: 200px;
    left: 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    padding: 2%;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.locked,.locked:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #666 !important;
    opacity: 0.3;
}

#gallery a {
    perspective: 100px;
    -webkit-perspective: 100px;
    -moz-perspective: 100px;
    -ms-perspective: 100px;
    float: left;
}

#gallery img {
    margin-bottom: -15px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#gallery .a img {
    transform: rotateY(15deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(15deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(15deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(15deg);
}

#gallery .g img {
    transform: rotateY(-15deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-15deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-15deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-15deg);
}

#gallery .b {
    padding-left: 10px;
}

#gallery .f {
    padding-right: 10px;
}

#gallery .b img {
    transform: rotateY(12deg);
    transform-origin: -100% 0% 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(12deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: -100% 0% 0;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(12deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: -100% 0% 0;
    -ms-transform: rotateY(12deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: -100% 0% 0;
}

#gallery .f img {
    transform: rotateY(-12deg);
    transform-origin: 200% 0% 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-12deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 200% 0% 0;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-12deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: 200% 0% 0;
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-12deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: 200% 0% 0;
}

#gallery .c img {
    transform: rotateY(9deg);
    transform-origin: -350% 0% 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(9deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: -350% 0% 0;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(9deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: -350% 0% 0;
    -ms-transform: rotateY(9deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: -350% 0% 0;
}

#gallery .e img {
    transform: rotateY(-9deg);
    transform-origin: 450% 0% 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-9deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 450% 0% 0;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-9deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: 450% 0% 0;
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-9deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: 450% 0% 0;
}

#gallery .d img {
    transform: rotateY(1deg);
    transform-origin: -5000% 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(1deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: -5000% 0 0;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(1deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: -5000% 0 0;
    -ms-transform: rotateY(1deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: -5000% 0 0;
}
```

i am happy with this as its seems to be working on all browsers which supports css3.
but the point is i am not getting desired output as expected.

Most importantly the spacing between the images is more consistent and better in the case of  `final output` but not the same in my case.

will only css3 make it achieve or i need to learn Canvas for it?

if only css3, what is missing?

Comment: Instead of slicing your images, you can use CSS perspective + transform:rotateY to give your images perspective.  Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/RmeeG/ which was adapted from this post on CSS-Tricks:  http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/perspective/

Comment: @markE .. i think you have provided better solutions. please add same as answer so that i can make it as solved..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of slicing your images, you can use CSS perspective + transform:rotateY to give your images perspective.

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/RmeeG/ which was adapted from this post on CSS-Tricks: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/perspective

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: ivory;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    font-size: 16px;
}
.wrapper {
    perspective: 1000px;
    margin: 4em auto;
    width: 37em;
}
.inner {
    width:150px;
    transition: .3s;
    transform: rotateY(35deg);
}
.inner figure {
    box-shadow: -6px 6px 2px -3px rgba(100, 100, 100, .1);
    width: 11em;
    padding: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 1em;
    background: rgba(250, 200, 200, 0.1);
    border: 1px solid rgba(250, 200, 200, .5);
}
.inner figcaption {
    text-align: center;
    margin: .5em 0;
    font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: darken(tomato, 15%);
}
.inner img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-filter: sepia(75%);
}
```

Comment: Just to add note on this answer, whatever i did per element, @markE garbed it into a `div` column wise and did the same.. but helps a lot.. thanks..